# auto-width for slide in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

As there is `fp-auto-height` for section. Is there anything similar to that for section's `slide` as well? Like,If I want to set a specific width for the a slide? 
I looked into this and found out this is the line where the things happen

```
<div class="fp-slidesContainer" style="width: 200%; transition: all 700ms ease; transform: translate3d(-1366px, 0px, 0px);"></div>
```

Now I tried to change the `transform` property like so

```
 $(".fp-next").click(function () {
    alert("clicked me");
    $(".fp-slidesContainer").css("transform","translate3d(-50vw, 0px, 0px) !important");
});
```

I have given 50vw as my next slide width is that.
But no luck whatsoever. What is wrong here?

Comment: Nop, unfortunately there's no such thing in fullPage.js at the moment.

Comment: Can you atleast show me a way,on how we can achieve this?

Comment: and why is this not working? `$("#fp-slidesContainer").css("transform","translate3d(-50vw, 0px, 0px)");`